# Why might OpenGL shader functions not be defined?

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, shader

I have a problem with shaders and openGL. Whenever I try to use them (even simple functions like glCreateShader​ or glCreateProgram​), my compiler (MinGW 4.6.1) tells me they haven't been defined.

Not even GLEW will compile correctly. Apparently the compiler doesn't know about GLchar, for example.

On the other hand, pretty much every other important OpenGL function (not related to shaders) seems to run fine with no problems. Weirdly, when I look into gl.h etc, I can't see the shader functions defined, so perhaps the compiler is right. Could I have a botched copy of the OpenGL headers, or am I likely doing something wrong?

Comment: Microsoft Windows ships with a library and headers that implement OpenGL 1.1. Without GLEW, or manually loading extensions at run-time by hand, you will not have access to GLSL (core in OpenGL 2.0, extension starting as far back as OpenGL 1.4). It is the responsibility of Installable Client Drivers (basically what your display driver ships with) to extend OpenGL beyond 1.1 on Windows, but this extension is done at run-time and not compile / link-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLEW is your immediate problem.  Get that working first, then you can see the newer OpenGL extensions.  Shader functions are not in gl.h.  I couldn't get GLEW to build myself, but did get GL3W to work.  I found I could not put freeglut.h before gl3w.h, and that stdlib.h had to be included before freeglut.h.  I found the tutorials at opengl-tutorial org very helpful in starting to use shaders.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this definitely pushed me in the right direction. (: